# Como funciona a inicialização do DbContext no Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Como a inicialização de um objeto `DbContext` funciona? As maneiras que sempre vejo é por injeção de dependência ou utilizando o `using`.

- O que aconteceria se eu inicializasse ele como um objeto normal? *(Segue um exemplo abaixo)*
- O que difere entre essas formas de inicialização?
- Em quais cenários cada uma delas é recomendada?

**Exemplo de inicialização normal que citei:**

```cs
public class CharacterUserWonderfulActivityUtil
{
    public CharacterUserWonderfulActivityUtil(GamePlayer player)
    {
        Player = player;
        GameDbContext = new GameDbContext();
    }

    private GameDbContext GameDbContext { get; }

    private GamePlayer Player { get; }

    public IList<CharacterUserWonderfulActivity> Activities { get; private set; }

    public IList<CharacterUserWonderfulActivityCondition> Conditions { get; private set; }

    public void Load()
    {
        Activities =
            GameDbContext.CharacterUserWonderfulActivities
                .Where(e => e.CharacterUserId == Player.Character.ID)
                .ToList();

        Conditions =
            GameDbContext.CharacterUserWonderfulActivityConditions
                .Where(e => e.CharacterUserId == Player.Character.ID)
                .ToList();
    }

    public void Save() => GameDbContext.SaveChanges();

    public void AddCondition(CharacterUserWonderfulActivityCondition condition)
    {
        Conditions.Add(condition);

        GameDbContext.CharacterUserWonderfulActivityConditions.Add(condition);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do ponto de vista geral isso é errado, mas preste atenção porque agora falarei do que é o comum de se fazer, depois explico que o `DbContext` é especial.

Toda classe que implementa `IDisposable` deve chamar o `Dispose()` de alguma forma. O `using` é a forma mais óbvia dentro de métodos. Quando ele faz parte de um objeto, independente de como ele foi colocado lá (Injeção de Dependência não resolve o problema por si só), esse objeto precisa implementar `IDisposable` e algo precisa chamar `Dispose()` dessa em algum lugar (alguns *frameworks* poderiam fazer isso por você). No `Dispose()` da sua classe precisa chamar o `Dispose()` do `DbContext` ou outras classes que implementem `IDdisposable`, ou seja, ele é viral.

Quando você não não chama o `Dispose()` o objeto fica largado ali até que o *garbage collector* chame o método para você. Isso é o fim do mundo? Para certos objetos não, e até onde eu sei o `DbContext` não é trágico. Mas não é a forma ideal, fica consumindo recursos sem necessidade. Não sei dizer se daria algum problema em algum código concorrente, mas acredito que não, pelo que eu vi por aí.

Se o que você usa chama esse código e morre pouco depois, ou seja, é uma execução efêmera, típica de *script*, então isso realmente não causará problema, ainda que não seja o ideal. Mas se fora algo que fica rodando por muito tempo, pode ser que em algum momento possa ter algum problema de memória.

Como na maioria das vezes funciona as pessoas acham que está certo.

A grosso modo deveria criar algo assim:

```
protected IDbContext GameDbContext {get;}
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    if (!disposedValue) {
        if (disposing) GameDbContext.Dispose();
        disposedValue = true;
    }
}
public void Dispose => Dispose(true);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Dispose.cs).

A recomendação específica para o `DbContext` é que ele seja usado só dentro de métodos, então se você o fizer não precisa se preocupar com isso. Se não fizer deveria saber explicar porque está evitando fazer o que é recomendado. Se não sabe, não faça.

O `DbContext` gerencia seu recurso (a conexão com o banco de dados) por conta própria, então o que é mais importante de fazer tão logo termine seu uso ele já resolve, por isso deixar o objeto solto não é um grande problema. Então todo acesso que for fazer ele abre e fecha a conexão por você. Se ele tem esse comportamento, por que acha que é tão importante manter o objeto na classe em vez de criá-lo só no momento que vai usar?

Na verdade há quem recomende nem usar o `using` com `DbContext`. E se não deveria em algo tão específico, na classe também não deveria descartar o objeto. Particularmente não gosto muito de tratar certos objetos com certas características como exceções, mas faz algum sentido. Talvez o `DbContext` nem deveria ter implementado `IDisposable` (entendo porque foi).

De fato quando usa com Injeção de Dependência é comum que o objeto nem seja descartado (depende de como usa a DI). E não é o fim do mundo.

Eu consigo entender a motivação de usar assim e não me parece que terá problemas. Mas não é errado fazer o certo :) Eu só não saberia dizer oque é mais eficiente (ainda que isso não mude muito).

Também já vi quem fala o oposto de tudo isto, eu não vou confirmar, nem negar, tome suas próprias conclusões lendo [o artigo](https://ardalis.com/avoid-wrapping-dbcontext-in-using/). Lembre-se que essa é uma posição diferente até do que a equipe do Entity Framework recomenda. Mas faz algum sentido.